# Undefined index: openid (laravel socialite QQ)

Tags: php, laravel

Socialite QQ is not working:

[image: this is issue image]
this is route file:

```
Route::group(
    ['prefix' => 'login'],
    function(\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router){
    $router->get('qq','Auth\LoginController@redirectToQq');
    $router->get('qq/callback','Auth\LoginController@handleQqCallback');
   }
);
```

this is `LoginController` file

```
public function redirectToQq()
{
    $clientId ='10xxxxx073';
    $clientSecret = "266db58XXXXXXXXXXXf77a174";
    $redirectUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/qq/callback";
    $config = new \SocialiteProviders\Manager\Config($clientId,$clientSecret,$redirectUrl);
    return Socialite::with('qq')->setConfig($config)->redirect();
}

public function handleQqCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('qq')->user();
    $accessTokenResponseBody = $user->accessTokenResponseBody;
    dd($user,$accessTokenResponseBody);
}
```

Comment: I think your OAuthentication service is not sending proper response. Check your client id and secret or your access token is invalid

Comment: client id and secret  is right... i used laravel/socialiteproviders--QQ ,and i accroding to demo is write..now i dont know what should i do